# Block access by IP Address Range on Tomcat 7 when accessing URL

Tags: java, tomcat

How do you configure the web.xml file on tomcat/application such that the following can be achieved:

**Allowed:**

- localhost/app/foo/bar/*

**Disallowed:**

- localhost/app/foo

Is there a way to do it without changing the source code? Changing the web.xml file is ok.

I've read http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/block-ip-address-apache-tomcat-filter but this alone doesn't solve the problem.

I've tried the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Remote IP Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>deny</param-name>
        <param-value>^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>denyStatus</param-name>
        <param-value>403</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>Allow quickview</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>denyStatus</param-name>
        <param-value>403</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Allow quickview</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote IP Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by "this alone doesn't solve the problem"? do you use spring context listener or not? Please show your web.xml

Comment: I considered declaring 2 filter-mappings in a way that it overlaps but only one of them is applied.

Comment: I would suggest having an apache http server in front of your tomcat server. Then you could have a simple RewriteRule to deny access.

Comment: I guess nginx or apache would easily do the job but i i can't do that at my shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i solved this by doing the following:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Allow quickview</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- disallowed, will throw 403 -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote IP Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The key was adding index.jsp as "/" alone does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<url-pattern>`s don't match the requirements stated in the question. You said you wanted to disallow `/app/foo/*` but allow `/app/foo`. You want this, then:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Allow quickview</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote IP Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```